# How to convert uint16_t image data to uint8_t image data

Tags: openimageio

How can I convert image data of 16 bit integer type to 8-bit integer type using openimageio c++ api?
Is this possible to do?

I have tried using convert_types() present in imageio.h but the result is not proper as I would have passed wrong 'n' value.
What parameter 'n' signifies convert_types()? what value should be passed?

Comment: By giving n = width * height * numberOf Channels, I am able to convert image data of 16 bit integer type to 8-bit integer type.
Is this the correct way to do ?

Comment: Yes. if target data should contain 8 bit channel per pixel then n = w * h * 1